# Lucene: searching for string matching a regex

Tags: java, regex, lucene

I use Lucene to search for specific patterns using a regular expression. A new use case came up where I need to look up a specific string matching a regex pattern. Good example would be to look up a prices in documents: prices can be written in many ways, just looking for "1256.88" as stored in the database is not enough. The value in the document may have a currency in front of it, behind it or even not present at all ("EUR 1256,88", "1256,88 EUR" or just "1256,88"). The value may have thousands separators or not. And of course this can be combined with each other. So I want to search for a specific, known price ("1256.88") being part of a regex at the same time. An example regex would be

```
[0-9]{1,10}*([\.|,][0-9]{0,2})?([\ ]?[€|$])?
```

1. What is the Lucene way of doing this? Is there a way to search with a regex AND an "example"?
2. Or do I have to search with a regex and then filter out wrong hits manually afterwards? How do I find out which strings triggered the match?

Comment: Mail address as a whole string? Please show some inputs that you want to find and some that you don't.

Comment: Sorry, your edit did not clear things out. Do you mean you want to match any string containing a substring? `.*1256,88.*`?

Comment: No, substrings will not help as the number itself can have different shapes.

Comment: *I want to search for a specific, known number being part of a regex* - what is the regex? Please add it to the question.

Comment: What a strange regex. So, you have `[0-9]{1,10}([.,][0-9]{0,2})?( ?[€$])?` regex that matches texts like `1234567890.12€`. Now, what do you need?

Comment: If I run this regex on a document it often happens to find several prices (two prices and their total, e. g.). I need to make sure that I get a (1) a price and (2) the correct price.

Comment: Try `.*1256[,.]88 *[€$].*`, although I am not sure what you need. Requirements must be clear, like "a number followed with a currency symbol should be matched".

Comment: The requirement would be "a given number with up to four decimal points written with or without thousand separators in multiple language formats preceded or followed by either a currency symbol or abbreviation should be matched". Sorry, it is that complicated.

Comment: Ok, so you have a `1256,88`. And you only want to match a string when you have `EUR 1256,88`, or `1256,88 EUR` or `USD 1256,88` or `1256,88 USD` or `$1256,88` or `1256,88€`... right? 1) How many currencies do you need to support? 2) Try `.*(1256,88 *([€$]|EUR|USD)|([€$]|EUR|USD) *1256,88).*`. Note there is a way to make it match at word boundaries if you replace `.*` with `(.*[^A-Z0-9_])?` at the start and `([^A-Z0-9_].*)?` at the end.

Comment: Does it work for you?